# Coverity deflect: - String length miscalculation (BAD_ALLOC_STRLEN)

Tags: c, string, malloc, strlen, coverity

I have a coverity deflect to be fixed but I am not sure about it. I have a function (`void my_function(a_type *my_variable)`) with the following problematic line of code:

```
body = malloc(strlen(&((my_type*) *my_variable)->Param2.body[1]) +1);
```

where `body` is an `unsigned char*`.

The Coverity message:

```
String length miscalculation (BAD_ALLOC_STRLEN)
Using "strlen(((my_type *)*my_variable)->Param2.body + 1)" 
instead of "strlen(((my_type *)*my_variable)->Param2.body) + 1" 
as an argument to "malloc" might be an under-allocation.
```

---

Now, given the `strlen` function call, which looks like this:

```
strlen(&((my_type*) *my_variable)->Param2.body[1])
```

and this line is identical to:

```
strlen(&((my_type*) *my_variable)->Param2.body + 1)
```

So this should be changed according to the message, and the result would be:

```
body = malloc((strlen(&((my_type*) *my_variable)->Param2.body)+1) +1);
```

Why is bad such an argument for `malloc`? I do not see what is the actual problem here so I am unsure about this solution and/or its necessity.

Additional information is that, `&((my_type*) *my_variable)->Param2.body[1]` (simply `&Param2.body[1]`) will be copied into `body` using `strcpy`, like:

```
strcpy(body, &((my_type *) *my_variable)->Param2.body[1]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached that conclusion [@rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) was correct. Considering the following simulation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Param2{
    char* body;
}Param2;

int main()
{
    Param2 test;
    test.body = "test_string\0";
    printf("%s, size: %d + 1 terminating null\n\n",test.body, strlen(test.body));

    printf("original:                %d \n", (strlen(&test.body[1]) + 1));
    printf("what coverity thinks:    %d \n", strlen(test.body + 1));
    printf("what coverity suggests:  %d \n", (strlen(test.body) + 1));
    printf("a more transparent way:  %d \n\n", (strlen(test.body + 1) + 1));

    return 1;
}
```

This is the output:
   [image: ![enter image description here]

There are three cases (4th is the same as 1st). The allocated memory can be seen on the image above for all cases. Now, if we want to copy the source string from the 2. byte (`&body[1`]), that would mean 10 bytes of data in the example. And according to the strcpy [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/):

> To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination shall
>   be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the
>   terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with
>   source.

We need one more for the null termination giving us 11 bytes to be allocated. Coverity believes that we are allocating 10 bytes, and suggest to allocate 12.

But as we can see, the original code allocates 11 bytes which is the exact number of bytes we need here, making the coverity deflect false positive.

Answer (score 1):

No, `...body[1]` and `...body + 1` are **not** identical. The first has a type that is the element type of the `body` array, the second has type *ptr-to-element-type*. Read your C book again :-)

Coverity tries to tell you that you make the same error as in

```
char foo[42];
/* write a string to foo */
bar = malloc (strlen(foo + 1)); /* which is strlen(&foo[1]) */
```

when the correct code is

```
bar = malloc (strlen(foo) + 1);
```

Comment: In effect, OP wrote `strlen(&body[1])+1` which is precisely correct for a copy of the suffix starting at the second character (provided you know `body` has at least one character). This seems to have confused both Covertly and various SO folk, but it seems fine to me, and arguably better than `strlen(body)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the paranthesis.

The `+ 1` in the coverity suggestion is *outside* the `strlen(...)`

I think coverity gets worried because you want to take `strlen` from index 1 instead of index 0. Coverity would expect index 0 as starting point - like:

```
body = malloc(strlen(&((my_type*) *my_variable)->Param2.body[0]) +1);
                                                             ^
```

which is also

```
body = malloc(strlen(((my_type*) *my_variable)->Param2.body) +1);
              ^                                            ^
            No & operator                                No [0]
```

as suggested by coverity